# Why does dict(enumerate(example)) return a randomized dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enumerate

When I run this simple program:

```
example: {'left', 'right', 'up', 'down'}
new_dict = dict(enumerate(example))
print(new_dict)
```

each run results in a different (index, value) pair. For example:

```
MacBook-Air:Desktop mymac$ python3 example.py
{0: 'right', 1: 'down', 2: 'left', 3: 'up'}
MacBook-Air:Desktop mymac$ python3 example.py
{0: 'left', 1: 'up', 2: 'down', 3: 'right'}
MacBook-Air:Desktop mymac$ python3 example.py
{0: 'down', 1: 'left', 2: 'right', 3: 'up'}
```

Why is that?

Comment: Your `example` is a set. Did you mean to use a list?

Comment: @user2357112 `example` is a set, yes. But I'm using `dict(enumerate(example))` to convert it into an enumerate object first and then a dictionary object.

Comment: But sets are unordered...

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks!

Comment: `dict` objects are unordered in Python < 3.7. And `set` objects are always unordered

Comment: The question remains why the same code produces different results each time it is ran.  Even if this is within its specification, the _why_ isn't clear yet.

Answer (score 1):

from the docs [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**hash**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)

> Note By default, the `__hash__()` values of `str`, `bytes` and `datetime` objects are “salted” with an unpredictable random value. Although they remain constant within an individual Python process, they are not predictable between repeated invocations of Python.
>
> Changing hash values affects the iteration order of dicts, sets and other mappings.
>
> *Changed in version 3.3:* Hash randomization is enabled by default.